# asp.net page cannot insert html tags in textbox to database due to offending characters

Tags: asp.net, html, tags, insertion

I have a basic form for submission in a detailview aspx page.

On of my textareas contains html code `<br>`. Whenever I try to do an insert, it fails, and I get a generic:

> The status code returned from the server is 500

I know the issue is the html code offending `<br>` because when removed, it inserts fine.

Is there a setting for the templateview for this field to allow html tags be allowed on the insertion?

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: What's the datatype of the field you're saving the HTML in?

Comment: On the form it is a text box with multiple rows. On the database, its a varchar(MAX) so able to take many characters.

Answer (score 0):

Any HTML in a textbox in asp.net web forms (assuming web forms) will cause this error.  You need to encode it in JavaScript, set the ValidateRequest property on the @Page attribute to false, or use some other utility (there are some out there, don't know of a specific one, maybe the HTML agility pack?).

Comment: Thank you Brian - I did set the validaterequest property to false, but  not sure how to encode the field to javascript? I am using the detailsview. Sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: if you set ValidateRequest to false, HTML can be posted back without requiring coding.  My answer was an either or condition, so turning that off will solve it.  Note, please be careful, because this can open the page up to XSS requests...

Answer (score 0):

In your Page Declaration ensure that ValidateRequest="false"...beware, this opens you up to XSS, Cross Site Scripting.

Ensure theat you encode the Data from the textarea before sending it to your Database, then when you return it to display, you'll Decode it.

From Microsoft.
**Encode Output

Use the HttpUtility.HtmlEncode method to encode output if it contains input from the user or from other sources such as databases. HtmlEncode replaces characters that have special meaning in HTML-to-HTML variables that represent those characters. For example, < is replaced with < and " is replaced with ". Encoded data does not cause the browser to execute code. Instead, the data is rendered as harmless HTML.

Similarly, use HttpUtility.UrlEncode to encode output URLs if they are constructed from input.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx